# IIFE Fibonacci function without value

Tags: javascript, function, loops, fibonacci, iife

guys.
Hope everything is well with you.

I need to make an IIFE function, which can be declared without entering of any values:

```
const fibonacciConst = function fibonacciFunction() {
        // using helper function;
}

fibonacciConst(); // 1 in console.log
fibonacciConst(); // 1 in console.log
fibonacciConst(); // 2 in console.log
fibonacciConst(); // 3 in console.log
fibonacciConst(); // 5 in console.log
```

Mine code is working only with value in IIFE, that's the problem:

```
function fibonacciFunction() { 
    (function helperFibonacci(n) {
    let a = 0, b = 1, c = n;
    for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    console.log(c);
    return c;
})(8); // without value here will be 'undefined'
}

const fibonacciConst = fibonacciFunction();

fibonacciConst; // 21 in console.log
```

I understood that in this task we need 2 functions: 1 function will be declaring another IIFE function inside, which is calculating result.
The solution is preferably as simple as possible.
Unfortunately, most solutions in google require you to enter a value, or difficult way with array, arrow functions etc. :(

Comment: It could be done that way, but you really want is a generator function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: look at this this way: if your desired function is pure, it returns the same result every time, so it has to be impure and carry state. The state must be saved in a variable external to that function. It is impossible to write a function that returns different results with the same arguments and doesn't involve external state (or input, for that matter) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. I realized that my inner function returns undefined value every time without entering data. To fix that I need to make my outer function to take values and pass it to inner function, which is calculating fibonacci figure. 

But I can't catch the idea how I can make my outer function to do it. How it can accept values and pass it to my inner function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the state around somehow. One option would be a closure:

```js
function makeFibonacci() {
    let a = 0, b = 1

    function inner() {
        [a, b] = [b, a + b]
        return a
    }

    return inner
}

let fib = makeFibonacci()

console.log(fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), fib(), )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!
I also add console.log before returning of the value so we can only call variable at the end without extra code.
Thanks! Have a good day ahead!